# Public key length

Tags: cryptography, key-management, digital-signature

I was wondering if there was (and I hope there is) a standard for public key size for ECDH (Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman) and ECDSA (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm) for every curve type over prime fields (192, 224, 256, 384 and 521).

Answer (score 10):

An ECDSA or ECDH public key is a curve point -- so it has the size of its curve. If you prefer, for EC-based cryptographic algorithm, we do not really talk about standard *sizes* but of standard *curves*.

There is no problem in having many people sharing the same curve -- it does not make them share private keys or anything like that. On the other hand, creating a new curve is very complex and expensive, due to point counting and all that. So a few standard curves have been defined; the most well known and supported are those from [FIPS 186-3](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf), published by NIST. There are 15 such curves, out of which 5 use "prime fields", i.e. integers modulo a big prime -- with length, respectively, 192, 224, 256, 384 and 521 bits. If you decide to use the P-256 curve, then, *by definition*, your public key will be a point on that curve, represented as two values in the 256-bit field (the two values being the point coordinates X and Y).

Out of tradition, we may say that P-256 is a "256-bit curve" because the number of possible curve points happens to be a prime number between 2<sup>255</sup> and 2<sup>256</sup>. So if you need, for some legal/marketing reasons, to express the size of your key as a number of bits, you say "256". Note that you cannot directly compare key sizes for distinct algorithms (a 1024-bit RSA key is *not* "stronger" than a 256-bit ECDSA key).

Comment: I'm aware of what they are. Let's say that we're using ECDH and that the shared secret has been computed. You want to send a public key to the other party and you are expecting his public key. What would be the expected size of these keys depending on the curve that generated them?

Comment: need more explanation about ECDSA with example